# change ggplot2 dimensions used in plotly r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, dimensions

For some reason, when I render a ggplot2 object into plotly it changes the dimensions of the plot. For some plots this is no big deal but for maps, it causes massive distortions. The only way I know to alter the dimensions via the width and height options when using `ggplotly()`. However, I need to add additional options that override default selections for the plot, thus I use `plotly_build()`. Once I render that, how do I toggle the dimensions? Here is some reproducible code:

```
#Load dependencies
library(rgeos)
library(stringr)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

#Function to download and import shapefile
dlshape=function(shploc, shpfile) {
  temp=tempfile()
  download.file(shploc, temp)
  unzip(temp)
  shp.data <- sapply(".", function(f) {
    fp <- file.path(temp, f)
    return(readOGR(".",shpfile))
  })
}

shape <- dlshape(shploc="http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/IRN_adm_shp.zip", 
                   "IRN_adm1")[[1]]

shape.ft <- fortify(shape, region="ID_1")
data<-merge(shape.ft, shape, region="id", by.x = "id", by.y = "ID_1")

gg<-ggplot(data, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = example1, group = group, label = example2, label2=example3)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightgrey", high = "darkred", name='Index') +xlab("")+ylab("") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))


ggpotly(gg, width = 1000, height = 750)
```

That works but I need to add a custom tooltip. Therefore, I need to rely on the following instead:

```
plotly_build(gg)
```

That, on the other hand, as you can see has the same dimensions as the previous code produces IF THE PREVIOUS CODE didnt include the width and height options. How can I toggle the width and height options using plotly_build? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `> shape.ft <- fortify(shape, region="ID_1")` gives `Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE`

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, works on my build. R version 3.3.0  mac, perhaps check your ggplot2 install and just to be safe install rgeos